# AWS X-Ray Python SDK get_service_graph

Tags: json, datetime, aws-lambda, boto3, aws-xray

I am trying to get JSON using get_service_graph() provided by AWS X-Ray Python SDK in AWS Lambda function. [reference link](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/xray.html#XRay.Client.get_service_graph)

```
import boto3
from datetime import datetime

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    client = boto3.client('xray')

    response1 = client.get_service_graph(
        StartTime=datetime(2017, 5, 20, 12, 0),
        EndTime=datetime(2017, 5, 20, 18, 0)
    )

    return response1
```

However, when I passed StartTime and EndTime parameters, stack trace reports datetime type is not JSON serializable. I even tried the following way.

```
response1 = client.get_service_graph(
        StartTime="2017-05-20 00:00:00",
        EndTime="2017-05-20 02:00:00"
)
```

What's weird is, if EndTime is set as "2017-05-20 01:00:00", there is no error generated. Other than that, the same error occurred.

```
    {
      "stackTrace": [
        [
          "/usr/lib64/python2.7/json/__init__.py",
          251,
          "dumps",
          "sort_keys=sort_keys, **kw).encode(obj)"
        ],
        [
          "/usr/lib64/python2.7/json/encoder.py",
          207,
          "encode",
          "chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)"
        ],
        [
          "/usr/lib64/python2.7/json/encoder.py",
          270,
          "iterencode",
          "return _iterencode(o, 0)"
        ],
        [
          "/var/runtime/awslambda/bootstrap.py",
          104,
          "decimal_serializer",
          "raise TypeError(repr(o) + \" is not JSON serializable\")"
        ]
      ],
      "errorType": "TypeError",
      "errorMessage": "datetime.datetime(2017, 5, 20, 1, 53, 13, tzinfo=tzlocal()) is not JSON serializable"
    }
```

I did try only use date, like datetime(2017, 5, 20). However, if I use two consecutive days as StartTime and EndTime, the runtime complains the interval can't be more than 6 hours. If I use same date, it only returns empty JSON. I don't know how to get granularity of get_service_graph().

I think Python SDK for AWS X-Ray might be premature, but I'd still like to seek help from someone who had the same experience. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

the right way is using `datetime(2017, 5, 20)` not a string... but can you try using only date... without time? at least the AWS docs shows an example exactly like yours but only yyyy-mm-dd without time

Comment: I did try only use date. If I use two consecutive days as StartTime and EndTime, the runtime complains the interval can't be more than 6 hours. If I use same date, it only returns empty JSON. I don't know how to get granularity of get_service_graph().

Comment: try `int(datetime.datetime(2017,5,20,1,0,0).strftime("%s")) * 1000` or without the `* 1000`

in JS it accepts epoch number datetime, maybe on python too

Comment: the other format in JS that can be used is `Wed Dec 31 1969 16:00:00 GMT-0800 (PST)`

Comment: You should be able to specify both date and time with second resolution.

Comment: I tried your solution, but seems like StartTime can't take int.        

{
"errorType": "ParamValidationError",
  "errorMessage": "Parameter validation failed:\n Invalid type for parameter StartTime, value: 1495242000000, type: <type 'int'>, valid types: <type 'datetime.datetime'>, timestamp-string"
}

Comment: seems like a bug in python sdk, you are using the last version of boto3 right?